# Get field name from an object retrieved by orm query

Tags: python, django

I have a small Django app, and when I query my DB with django orm I get my objects list.
What I want is the name of the db column where the query has matched.
Is possible?

Thanks in advance!

```
results = Verbs.objects.filter(
        Q(fps__icontains = " " + word_name + " ") | Q(fps__endswith = " " + word_name) | Q(fps__startswith = word_name + " ") |
        Q(sps__icontains = " " + word_name + " ") | Q(sps__endswith = " " + word_name) | Q(sps__startswith = word_name + " ") |
        Q(tps__icontains = " " + word_name + " ") | Q(tps__endswith = " " + word_name) | Q(tps__startswith = word_name + " ") |
        Q(fpp__icontains = " " + word_name + " ") | Q(fpp__endswith = " " + word_name) | Q(fpp__startswith = word_name + " ") |
        Q(spp__icontains = " " + word_name + " ") | Q(spp__endswith = " " + word_name) | Q(spp__startswith = word_name + " ") |
        Q(tpp__icontains = " " + word_name + " ") | Q(tpp__endswith = " " + word_name) | Q(tpp__startswith = word_name + " ")
        ).all()
```

What I want is the name of field where the query as matched. For example: fps or fpp ...

Comment: Could you please show your query and what kind of result you want to obtain from it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want--for each returned row it will print the matched fields, indented:

```
fields = ('fps', 'sps', 'tps', 'fpp', 'spp', 'tpp')
for r in results.values():
    print 'Row with id=%s:' % r['id']
    for f in fields:
        if word_name in str(r[f]):
            print '  Field %s matches' % f
```

Edited to account for non-string values and to look only at the desired fields.

Comment: this return me: 
argument of type 'long' is not iterable